# Using Custom Functions with "I" in Page Object and Custom Helper in CodeceptJS

Tags: helper, puppeteer, pageobjects, codeceptjs

Hi CodeceptJS Community,

- Is there a way to use custom defined functions (under steps_file.js) as **I. customFunction()** in page object files.
- Is there a way to use native codeceptjs functions (like **I.click()**) in my *custom helper files*

I couldn't find any help in the documentation and in other sources. Is there any way to achieve this?

- And is there any way to use xpath locators in puppeteer helper?

  this.helpers['Puppeteer'].page.click(xpath);

Comment: The question is, what is "I"?

Comment: Sorry for the title. I have thought my question was in CodeceptJS section. The title is corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem to use custom steps in pageObjects.
To avoid it, i passed the actor (I) as parameter to my pageObject function.

page object:

```
const I = actor();

       module.exports = {

           doSomething(I){
                 I.login();
           }
};
```

Test scenario:

```
Scenario('Test something' (I,pageObject)=>{
     pageObject.doSomething(I)
})
```

In this case, pageObjects will has access to all custom steps from I :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your sharing Matheus. I have used a different solution. Instead of writing "I" object in every page object method (which was also one option for me), I have created a custom helper file and written all methods using puppeteer helper like below;

```
async method() {
    await this.helpers['Puppeteer'].click(xpath);
}
```

I can call this method both in tests and page objects

```
I.method();
```

Comment: The question is, how to enable `async method(path) { I.click(path) }`

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and when I looked into the typescripts definitions I noticed that `actor()` which is required in every page object etc. has custom steps arguments.

So this worked for me to extend the `const I = actor();` witht the custom steps form steps_file.js;

```
const customSteps = require('./steps_file');
const I = actor(customSteps());
```

After that, I can use all methods in page objects like in tests scenarios which are accessing the methods from steps_file.js